# Spark SQL selecting ambiguous column by running a SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which is a join of two other dataframes.
I want to perform a run a SQL query but I don't know how to distinguish the *id* columns. 
I tried specifying the original table but no luck.

**Schemas**:

blogs:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

comments:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- blog_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |-- comment: string (nullable = true)
```

blogs joined with comments

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- blog_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |-- comment: string (nullable = true)
```

**Attempted queries**:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT id FROM joined")
12:17:26.981 [run-main-0] INFO org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser - Parsing command: SELECT id FROM joined
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'id' is ambiguous, could be: id#7, id#23.; line 1 pos 7

scala> spark.sql("SELECT blogs.id FROM joined")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`blogs.id`' given input columns: [blog_id, id, comment, title, author, author, id]; line 1 pos 7;
'Project ['blogs.id]
+- SubqueryAlias joined, `joined`
   +- Join FullOuter, (id#7 = blog_id#24)
      :- Project [_1#0 AS id#7, _2#1 AS author#8, _3#2 AS title#9]
      :  +- LocalRelation [_1#0, _2#1, _3#2]
      +- Project [_1#14 AS id#23, _2#15 AS blog_id#24, _3#16 AS author#25, _4#17 AS comment#26]
         +- LocalRelation [_1#14, _2#15, _3#16, _4#17]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have joined the two dataframes as below:

```
val df = left.join(right, left.col("name") === right.col("name"))
```

Where join is made on column `name` - and this column is deplicated in joined-df.

Resolve by this: (specifying the join-column)

```
val df = left.join(right, Seq("name"))
```

This way, you can remove duplicate columns in joined df; and query without any issue.

Comment: The join wasn't on the problematic column. It was id=blog_id

Comment: Ohh!!! Then, you need to assignn alias while joining to avoid ambiguous

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't require me to assign aliases explicitly. I mean if I run a query at the SQL level that mentions which table the column belongs to it works. I'm looking to do the same on the Spark SQL level..

Answer (score -4):

You have a typo in your query.

```
spark.sql("SELECT blogs.id FROM joined")
```

It should be

```
spark.sql("SELECT blog.id FROM joined")
```

Comment: No there is no typo.. why would it be blog and not blogs?